# What is the best defense when playing against Miami online?

Tags: nba2k12

What is the best defense when playing against Miami online? It seems there is no way to stop Lebron from dunking.

Answer (score 2):

Run a 2-3 Zone defense. In NBA 2k12, Lebron has 2 hot spots behind the arc, and those are both to the right of the free throw line.

With that said, Lebron shoots a very low percentage anywhere else behind the arc, as well as when taking a fadeaway jumper inside the arc. If you can force him to do either of these, you will have a much easier time defending him.

The 2-3 zone will put your three biggest guys around the hoop. This will make your life much easier when defending anybody who is driving.

In the way of teams, I would have to go with the Indiana Pacers. Roy Hibbert is a monster inside and will give your team the edge.

Have fun and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would pick the mavericks and run a zone that forces him to go to the arc instead of pushing foward